# Merge the new-england tag and the us-new-england tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tagging

Should the [us-new-england](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-new-england) tag be an alias for the [new-england](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-england) tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a mod should merge the tags.

Comment: I just edited the questions to replace the tags since the `us-new-england` tag was only used twice. Hopefully the tag won't be recreated, and will rest in peace.